# Print certain part in a Regular Expression?

Tags: regex, bash

For example, a file contains multiple strings, where some look like this:
`--EX "ABCDEFG"`

I created the following regular expression to see if the line matches:
`^--EX\ \".*\"$`
My question is now, can I somehow extract the content of `.*` in order to just get `ABCDEFG`?
Are regular expressions suitable for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put parentheses around the part you want to get.

```
^--EX\ \"(.*)\"$
```

Then in whatever your code, it will be match 1, most implementations of regex imply match 0 is the full match, and match 1 will be the first set of parenthesis, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

you can get it via sed:

```
$ echo "--EX "ABCDEFG"" | sed 's/^--EX \(.*\)$/\1/'
ABCDEFG
```

Answer (score 1):

On the command line you must enter your command precisely as shown here:

```
sed -e "s/^--EX \"\(.*\)\"$/\\1/g" filename
```

Comment: if you use single quotes you can avoid some of your escaping: `'s/^--EX "\(.*\)"$/\1/g'`